# Remove or Set attribute value after another element been selected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to remove the `contenteditable` attribute, or at-least set it to false when another element has been clicked. This is what I tried so far:

```js
group.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    group.removeClass("selected");
    isEditable.attr('contenteditable', false)
    $this.addClass("selected");
    isEditable.attr('contenteditable', true).css("cursor", "text");
});
```

Preview & all code: http://jsbin.com/ekufeb/3 (Select one of the text)

The purpose is to apply css to the selected element only `cursor: pointer;` but when I select one element, it applies to all that is in the isEditable variable. Which is:

```
isEditable = $(".grouptitle, .username, .text");
```

Any way of doing this? Hopefully the preview will help.

Comment: Have you considered using the "blur" event? Would that work in your situation? http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: what is your end goal? why would you need to remove contenteditable when another element is clicked? It stops being editable as soon as you click out anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `removeAttr` to remove any attribute from an element. so in your case it will be

```
isEditable.removeAttr('contenteditable');
```

If you want to select elements which has `contenteditable` attribute or it is true use this.

```
isEditable = $(".grouptitle, .username, .text").filter(function(){
            return !$(this).attr('contenteditable') 
                   || ($(this).attr('contenteditable') == false);
});
```